# MySQL subquery with two tables count and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database of doctors and hospital joined by hospitaldoctor table.

I have to List town, amount of hospitals in each town, but only hospitals which have more than 5 doctors.

```
SELECT hospital.town, count(town)
FROM hospital 
WHERE hospital.id = (
    SELECT count(hospital_id)
    FROM hospital_doctor GROUP BY hospital_id
    HAVING count(hospital_id)>5 )
GROUP BY town
```

this is my query but MySQL returns me that subquery returns more than 1 row.

HOSPITAL

[image: HOSPITAL]

HOSPITAL DOCTOR

[image: HOSPITAL DOCTOR]

How i should write this query?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with basically the same structure:

```
Select h.town, count(*)
from hospital h
where h.id in (select hd.hospital_id
               from hospital_doctor hd
               group by hd.hospital_id
               having count(*) > 5
              )
group by h.town ;
```

Note the following:

- You want to use `in` not `=`, because the subquery could return more than one row.
- The subquery should be returning the hospital id not the count.
- Use table aliases and qualified column names whenever a table refers to more than one table.

Comment: Thank you gor solving my problem and for goot advice. Greetings :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select hospital.town, count(town) 
from hospital 
where 
    hospital.id in ( 
        select hospital_id 
        from hospital_doctor 
        group by hospital_id 
        having count(hospital_id)>5 
    ) 
group by town
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT h.town,  count(h.town)
FROM 
(
    SELECT hospital_id
    FROM hospital_doctor GROUP BY hospital_id
    HAVING count(doctor_id)>5 
) s1 
left outer join hospital h on (s1.hospital_id=h.id)  
GROUP BY h.town
```